# Ionic 3 Slidescreen page seems to be unrecognized by my code

Tags: ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 and it seems that the code that I'm using have a bit of a problem. It doesn't direct to my slides screen which is I already created. It display the loader authentication right after my splash screen but it directs to my root page which is the 'TabsPage'. What I want to happen is that after my splash screen is finished, it will now direct to my slide screen just once if the user already accessed the application. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any = TabsPage;
  loader: any;

  showSplash = true; 

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController , public storage: Storage, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.presentLoading();
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      timer(3000).subscribe(() => this.showSplash = false)

        this.storage.get('introShown').then((result) => {

          if(result){
            this.rootPage = TabsPage;
          } else {
            this.rootPage = IntroPage;
            this.storage.set('introShown', true);
          }

          this.loader.dismiss();

        });

      });

    }

    presentLoading() {

      this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Authenticating..."
      });

      this.loader.present();

    }
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage

      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        Camera,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```